# How to make jquery ui sortable wai-aria compliant?

Tags: jquery-ui, wai-aria

What is the best procedure to make jquery ui sortable keyboard accessible? Ideally the user should be able to assign a position/number to each item in a list in an accessible way. The only info I can find is here https://medium.com/salesforce-ux/how-to-describe-complex-designs-for-users-with-disabilities-ba05f5224130#.o9kitc408 but the implementation specifics are not included.

Thanks

Comment: Have you already read through https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#grid ?

Comment: grid is more like a table. jquery sortables are just reordering ui controls.

Comment: Curious if you ever figured this out?